# Sort array in descending order and collect the changes of main array in new array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
public static int[] sortByScores(double[] scores){

        double temp;
        int i,j;
        int[] scoreIndex = new int[3]; 

        for (i = 0; i <= scores.length; i++)            
            for (j = i+1; j < scores.length; j++) {
                if (scores[i] < scores[j]) {
                    temp = scores[i];
                    scores[i] = scores[j];
                    scores[j] = temp;
                    scoreIndex[i] = j;
                    scoreIndex[j] = i;
                }
            }

        return scoreIndex;
}
```

This method sort the "scores" array in descending order and store which index key is changed from the array in "scoreIndex" array.

This method doesn't work if I enter `1,3,2,4`

Is they any better way to store the index key changes log?

Example if 1 enter:

```
1
2
4
3
```

Sorted will be:

```
4
3
2
1
```

And sortIndex should be:

```
Key   Value 
0     3
1     2
2     0
3     1
```

Comment: Take a look here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @LanceToth Sorting algorithm is not the problem in this case, but `changes of array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually get the array containing the proper ordering of the elements at certain indices without sorting this array, for example, by doing this:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            for(int j = i; j < scores.length; j++) {
                if(scores[scoreIndex[j]] > scores[scoreIndex[i]]) {
                    int temp = scoreIndex[j];
                    scoreIndex[j] = scoreIndex[i];
                    scoreIndex[i] = temp;
                }

            }
   }
```

In short, at the beginning of this method we are creating an array which contains the current order of indices in your scores[] array, this is `0, 1, ..., scores.length-1`. Then, we perform an operation similar to standard sorting but not in terms of the scores[] array, but in terms of the scoreIndex[] array. 
Once we have this array sorted, we can create another array and and place its elements at the appropriate position by:

```
        double[] copy = new double[scores.length];
        for(int k = 0; k < scores.length; k++) {
            copy[k] = scores[k];
        }
        for(int n = 0; n < scores.length; n++) {
            scores[n] = copy[scoreIndex[n]];
            System.out.println(scores[n]);
        }
```

So, to put it together:

```
public static int[] sort(double[] scores) {
        int[] scoreIndex = new int[scores.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            scoreIndex[i] = i;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            for(int j = i; j < scores.length; j++) {
                if(scores[scoreIndex[j]] > scores[scoreIndex[i]]) {
                    int temp = scoreIndex[j];
                    scoreIndex[j] = scoreIndex[i];
                    scoreIndex[i] = temp;
                }

            }
        }
        double[] copy = new double[scores.length];
        for(int k = 0; k < scores.length; k++) {
            copy[k] = scores[k];
        }
        for(int n = 0; n < scores.length; n++) {
            scores[n] = copy[scoreIndex[n]];
            System.out.println(scores[n]);
        }


        return scoreIndex;
    }
```

Comment: This is awesome, this method works for repeated number also, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

First, you should declare `scoreIndex` as:

```
int[] scoreIndex = new int[scores.length];
```

And, in every outer loop, you find the max element, set it as `scores[i]`, at the same time, set `scoreIndex[indexOfMaxElement] = i`. To achieve this, you also need a copy of the origial array.

Here is the complete code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] array = new double[] {1, 2, 4, 3};
        int[] result = sortByScores(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(result[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] sortByScores(double[] scores){

        int[] scoreIndex = new int[scores.length];
        double[] copy = new double[scores.length];
        boolean[] records = new boolean[scores.length];

        // copy
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            copy[i] = scores[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            // find the max element
            for (int j = i + 1; j < scores.length; j++) {
                if (scores[i] < scores[j]) {
                    double temp = scores[i];
                    scores[i] = scores[j];
                    scores[j] = temp;

                }
            }
            // set the max element's index
            for (int k = 0; k < copy.length; k++) {
                if (copy[k] == scores[i] && !records[k]) {
                    scoreIndex[k] = i;
                    records[k] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return scoreIndex;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, this method does not work if a number is repeated, try this  {1, 3, 4, 3}

Comment: Hello buddy, it's very easy to overcome it. Just create another array to record the visited element. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

My one worked too but @user6690200 your one is way better.

```
public static int[] sortByScores(double[] scores){

        double temp,temp2;
        int i,j;
        int[] scoreIndex = new int[3]; 

        double[] scoreBackup = new double[scores.length]; 
        double[] scoreBackup2 = new double[scores.length];


        // Generating unique score, beacuse student can have same score

        for(i=0;i<scores.length;i++) 
            scoreBackup[i] = scores[i]*(i+1);

        for(i=0;i<scores.length;i++) 
            scoreBackup2[i] = scores[i]*(i+1);


        for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)      {
            for (j = i+1; j < scores.length; j++) {
                if (scores[i] < scores[j]) {
                    temp = scores[i];
                    temp2 = scoreBackup2[i];
                    scores[i] = scores[j];
                    scoreBackup2[i] = scoreBackup2[j];
                    scores[j] = temp;    
                    scoreBackup2[j] = temp2;
                }
            }
        }

        for(i = 0; i<scores.length;i++) 
            for(j=0;j<scores.length;j++) 
                if(scoreBackup[i] == scoreBackup2[j])
                    scoreIndex[i] = j;


        return scoreIndex;

    }
```